# Add suffix to all files in the directory with an extension

Tags: bash

How to add a suffix to all files in the current directory in bash?

Here is what I've tried, but it keeps adding an extra `.png` to the filename.

```
for file in *.png; do mv "$file" "${file}_3.6.14.png"; done
```

Comment: Your variables are wrong. You assign `$item`, but then you use `$file`.

Comment: Well then... that worked. haha. I am so dumb, sorry for even posting this. I didn't even notice I called it item and then called it file. I was doing some Python work and I always use `for item in some_list:` and it carried through in my brain.

Comment: Note that your code keeps the original `.png` suffix in the middle, and adds another `.png` at the end, so you get `file.png_3.6.14.png`. See my solution that removes the middle suffix.

Comment: @Barmar or other powerful SO member: The question is legit, even though the OP managed to almost answer it by her/himself. How about editing this question (removing the failed attempt) and reopen the question? I don't consider it off-topic, and it receives quite some attention.

Comment: @normanius If we remove the failed attempt, there's no question. The solutions are in answers.

Comment: @Barmar My query today was "bash how to add suffix to files" which led me immediately to this question, and your answer was what I finally used myself. I just wondered why the question was flagged as "off-topic". Never mind, it was only a suggestion.

Comment: @normanius Because the main problem was just a trivial error of using the wrong variable, which is not really helpful for future readers.

Comment: @Barmar For me as a future reader (6 years later), this post _was_ useful, which is why I wanted to suggest to remove the "off-topic" label. See my edit. Maybe it becomes clearer what I meant. Feel free to revert :)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
for file in *.png; do
    mv "$file" "${file%.png}_3.6.14.png"
done
```

`${file%.png}` expands to `${file}` with the `.png` suffix removed.

Comment: Thank You sir, this was quite helpful. Yes, mine kept adding an extra `.png`.

Comment: One-liner: 
`for file in *.png; do mv "$file" "${file%.png}_3.6.14.png"; done `

Answer (score 27):

You could do this through rename command,

```
rename 's/\.png/_3.6.14.png/' *.png
```

Through bash,

```
for i in *.png; do mv "$i" "${i%.*}_3.6.14.png"; done
```

It replaces `.png` in all the `.png` files with `_3.6.14.png`.

- `${i%.*}` Anything after last dot would be cutdown. So `.png` part would be cutoff from the filename.
- `mv $i ${i%.*}_3.6.14.png` Rename original .png files with the filename+_3.6.14.png.

Comment: Yeah... command `man rename` shows the manual but `rename` is non-existent on Mac distro.

Comment: the man page is for the `rename(2)` system call, not the shell command.

Comment: Ah Yes, I see. Renaming with a prefix is easy via bash but suffix is a pain. I am guessing it has to do something with the file extension being there.

Comment: Please quote your variables.

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko updated. without quoting, it works for me.

Comment: @AvinashRaj even if it works it doesn't mean that there is no bug in your code. Try removing the quotes, then create a file called ``* .png``

Comment: Oh, thanks for your information. Here after i should follow.

Comment: on a Mac, you can use home-brew to install rename: `brew install rename`

Answer (score 2):

If you are familiar with regular expressions `sed` is quite nice.

a) modify the regular expression to your liking and inspect the output

`ls | sed -E "s/(.*)\.png$/\1_foo\.png/`

b) add the `p` flag, so that `sed` provides you the old and new paths. Feed this to xargs with -n2, meaning that it should keep the pairing of 2 arguments.

`ls | sed -E "p;s/(.*)\.png/\1_foo\.png/" | xargs -n2 mv`

Answer (score 2):

If you know how to rename a single file to your liking programmatically

```
fname=myfile.png
mv $fname ${fname%.png}_extended.png
```

you can batch apply this command with xargs:

```
find -name "*.png" | xargs -n1 bash -c 'mv $0 ${0%.png}_extended.png'
```

### Explanation

We pipe the list of files to xargs and tell it to process one line at a time with the `-n1` flag. We then tell xargs to call `bash` on each instance and provide it with the code to execute via the `-c` flag.
The `$0` references the first input argument the bash receives.
If you need other string substitutions than `${0%.png}` there are many cheat sheets such as https://devhints.io/bash.

For more complex substitutions you provide multiple arguments using `-n2`; these can be collected with `$0, $1, etc.`.

This use of `piping + xargs + bash -c` is fairly general.
In the short example above, beware that I assumed proper file names (without special characters).